# UITabelView changed Image in scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Every time I scroll the TableView, my images gets messed up, mainly the first row. I realy don`t kwon what to do.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    [cell.activityFotoBar startAnimating];
    cell.activityFotoBar.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

   if(!cell){
       cell = [[BarCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

    NSMutableDictionary *infoBar = [self.bares objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *nomeImagem = [infoBar objectForKey:@"foto"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:nomeImagem];
    NSURLRequest *requestImagem = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestImagem queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        if(connectionError == nil){
            cell.imageViewImagemBar.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [cell.activityFotoBar stopAnimating];
        }

    }];


    cell.labelNomeBar.text = [infoBar objectForKey:@"nome"];
    cell.labelEnderecoBar.text = [infoBar objectForKey:@"endereco"];
    cell.labelAvaliacaoBar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Votos: %@", [infoBar objectForKey:@"votos"]];

    return cell;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by messed up?

Comment: Suppose, you should not do the image loading in cellForRow

Comment: The image of the fisrt row get replaced by the third row, or fourth row, and so on. It is random.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because the asynchronous image request finishes after your cell scrolls off the screen and gets reused. Downloads complete "out of order", contributing to a visual confusion. Essentially, some of the cells put up for reuse by scrolling, are still "hot", in the sense that their image load is in progress. Reusing such cell creates a race between the old and the new image downloads.

You should change the strategy that you use to load the images: rather than sending a request and "forgetting" it, consider using `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` method, storing the connection in the cell, and calling `cancel` on it when `prepareForReuse` method is called. This way your reused cells would be "cold".

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to do an example for me? I`m kinda new in this. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoSoares I wouldn't be able to do a better job than Apple at this - take a look at their sample: [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebcache library. It contains a UIImageView category class which can load images from urls. I find it works well with tableviews

Answer (score 0):

The code should "almost" work. You just need to fix one issue to get it working (though not optimally):

When the asynchronous request `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` has been finished, the completion handler will be called. Then, you need to retrieve the cell again from the table view specifying the *indexPath* at the time the request has been started.

You just need to capture the *indexPath* within the block in order to get a reference that stays valid until after the block finishes.

The `UITableView`'s method to retrieve the cell is

`- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

If the return value (a cell) is `nil` the cell at index path *indexPath* is not visible.

So, the completion block will look as follows:

```
    if (error == nil && ... ) {
        BarCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
        if (cell) {
            cell.imageViewImagemBar.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [cell.activityFotoBar stopAnimating];
        }
    }
```

Which also safely handles the case where the cell is nil.

**Note:** while this "works" it's still a naïve approach. A more sophisticated approach would cache the (decoded) images and possibly has some "look ahead and eager eviction strategy" for better user experience and lower memory foot-print.

Note that `imageWithData:` may still be costly since it *may* require to decode, decompress and resize the image before it can be rendered. Basically, this can be performed beforehand,  with an offscreen context.